# Python, Selenium and Scrapy not working together?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I want to crawl the flight tickets from British Airways and store it in mongodb.
I am able to go past the search form but I can't scrape the given data.

My Spider:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from flight.items import FlightItem

class BASpider(Spider):
name = "BA"
allowed_domains = ["britishairways.com"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/en_za?DM1_Channel=PPC&DM1_Mkt=ZA&DM1_Campaign=APMEA_ZA_EN_PUREBRAND_MASTERBRAND&Brand=Y&gclid=CLvt24zsqMgCFUGg2wodds4Prw",
]

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="depCountry"]').is_displayed())

    departCountry_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id('depCountry')
    departCity_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id('from')
    oneWay = self.driver.find_element_by_id('journeyTypeOW')
    oneWay.click()
    dest_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id('planTripFlightDestination')
    date_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id('depDate')
    butt = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')
    departCountry_form.send_keys("South Africa")
    departCity_form.send_keys("Johannesburg")
    dest_form.send_keys("London")
    date_form.clear()
    date_form.send_keys("05/10/15")

    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.click(butt)
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(35)



def parse_post(self, response): 
    flightList = Selector(response).xpath('//table[@class="flightList directFlightsTable connectflights"]/tbody/tr')

    for flight in flightList:
        item = FlightItem()
        item['dTime'] = flight.xpath(
            'td[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[@class=" departure"]/div/div/span[1]/text()').extract()[0]
        item['aTime'] = flight.xpath(
            'td[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[@class=" arrival"]/span[1]/text()').extract()[0]
        item['flightNr'] = flight.xpath(
            'td[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[@class=" operator"]/div/div/span[2]/href').extract()[0]
        item['price_economy'] = flight.xpath(
            'td[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[@class=" priceselecter price-M ch3 col1"]/span/span[2]/label/text()').extract()[0]
        item['price_premium'] = flight.xpath(
            'td[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[@class=" priceselecter price-W ch3 col2"]/span/span[2]/label/text()').extract()[0]
        item['price_business'] = flight.xpath(
            'td[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[@class=" priceselecter price-C ch3 col3"]/span/span[2]/label/text()').extract()[0]
        yield item  

    self.driver.close()
```

I'm not getting any errors, it's just not scraping.

Comment: I got some spiders using selenium too, so they work, maybe you are missing something, could you share the logs, and make sure you are getting information on every xpath?  Where is your code calling `parse_post`?

Comment: I didn't check your code, but as answer to your question "Python, Selenium and Scrapy not working together?", I can tell you that you can use Scrapy with Selenium for sure. You can use this combination when your target site includes some ajax interaction that needs to be captured through the browser interaction. You can find an example here: http://www.6020peaks.com/2014/12/how-to-scrape-hidden-web-data-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get nothing is that `parse_post()` method is never called.

---

You might actually instantiate the `Selector` out of the `self.driver.page_source` directly inside the `parse()` callback:

```
selector = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
flightList = selector.xpath('//table[@class="flightList directFlightsTable connectflights"]/tbody/tr')

for flight in flightList:
    # ...
```

Comment: Where exactly should I call parse_post()? Sorry, im very new to this

Comment: @Jaco okay, updated the answer. Note that you should probably avoid having that `time.sleep()` call inside and use an explicit wait via webdriverwait - well, it's a different story anyway. Hope that helps.